# Unable to run a script inside docker compose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, bash, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file which on up, will be starting a mongo service. What I want to do is as soon as it starts the service, I want to create a database called 'abc' and create a collection 'xyz' into it.

This is what I have tried so far

**docker-compose file**

```
services:

  database: 
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    command: sh initialSetup.sh
```

I get the below error

Not sure why is that not able to open the script

[image]
**initialSetup.sh file**

```
#!/bin/sh
mongo < mongoInitialSetup.js
```

and
**mongoInitialSetup.js**

```
conn = new Mongo();
db = db.getSiblingDB('abc');
db.createCollection('xyz', {});
```

Add-on: It would be really great if someone could help me get this done with just the bash script without using the js file

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can place your database initialization scripts in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/. Look at 'Initializing a fresh instance' on this page https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below solution worked

```
services:

  database: 
    image: mongo
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: ${DATABASE_NAME}
    volumes:
      - ./initialSetup.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initialSetup.sh
```

and in the **initialSetup.sh**, I had

```
mongo -- "$MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE" <<EOF
    db.createCollection('images', {});
EOF
```